# What is a POSIX-compliant alternative to if (( ... ))?

Tags: shell, unix, posix

POSIX standardizes `$(( ... ))` as arithmetic syntax, as can be seen in section 2.6.4 of https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html

However, dash does not support `if (( ... ))` to test whether an arithmetic expression has a nonzero output.

How can this be done to be portable to all POSIX-compliant shells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `$(( ... ))` is POSIX-compliant, and `test` is POSIX-compliant, you can make `$(( ... ))` emit a result which you can then evaluate with `test` or its synonym `[`.

Because booleans in an arithmetic expression emit `1` for true or `0` for false, you can test directly against their result.

For example:

```
someVar=13
maxLimit=10

if [ "$(( someVar > maxLimit ))" -gt 0 ]; then
  echo "ERROR: someVar value of $someVar is greater than maximum of $maxLimit" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Why are the double quotes necessary?

Comment: Paranoia. If you had `IFS=0`, for instance, you could have the `10` replaced with `1`, or `0` replaced with a zero-argument list, etc.

Comment: I firmly believe it's better to write code defensively, such that one doesn't need to analyze whether unlikely scenarios are in fact reachable in determining correctness. An unquoted expansion in bash or sh is effectively asking the shell to do extra work (string-splitting and glob expansion); if you don't want that work, and you wouldn't write `.split()` in the same code in Python, why ask for it by leaving out quotes here?

Comment: Are the inside spaces of `[ ]` needed?

Comment: Depends on which specific ones you're asking about. The ones inside `$(( ))` are optional; the others are needed.